# trigger function when admin updates order status woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I created a function to insert custom data into a table and now I am wondering if there is any possibility or any hook available when admin updates the order status or order status is changed or updated automatically I need to run a query then is there any possibility available in wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this hook will work for your case:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'woocommerce_process_shop_order', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_process_shop_order ( $order_id, $order ) {
        //.......
}
```

Comment: this wil always run when admin wil update order right?

Comment: @KhurramKhan, Yes, it'll do, you can try yourself :)

Comment: this worked for me awesome thank you so very much but how can I verify get order status s thee any way to get it which order status is being changed